# Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0 and https and timeout error

Tags: https, timeout, msxml

We had a credit card form that was non-https.  When the submit was done it would call Paypal in https mode to process a credit card.   Never had any problems.  My boss understandable so wants the form to enter credit card data to be https.  When I do this now I get a timeout error using the MSxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0 object.

I tried setting the timeout to no avail.

Any suggestions on how to use the Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0 in classic ASP without getting the timeout error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to 6.0 and it solved the problem